# Display problem of selection list - flask and vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, flask

I am connecting flask and vue.js but I have a problem with my select.
I have the following line in my html code:

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-select" v-model="reftools">
<option value="" selected="true" disabled="disabled"></option>
  <option v-for="opt in status_reftools" v-bind:value="opt">{{ opt }}</option>
</select>
```

This line allows me to display the different options of my select,thanks also to the following line:

```
<script>
const Form = {
   data() {
     return {
      "comments": null,
      "status_reftools": [
      "Yes",
      "No",
      "Unknown"
      ],
      }
   },
   methods : {
    submit() {
       axios.post('formulaire', {
       "comments" : this.comments,
       "reftools" : this.reftools,     
       });
    }
   }
  };
  Vue.createApp(Form).mount('#section_formulaire');
</script>
```

Thanks to these lines that I combine with Flask, I can get the data from my list. The problem is that the different options are not displayed in the list (view picture).I have the impression that {{opt}} is removed when I run my flask script. How can this happen?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use {{'{{opt}}'}} instead {{opt}}